# How to Format a DataGrid column in code using a binding

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, binding, ivalueconverter, datagridtextcolumn

I can't figure out how to add the format parameter to the following DataGrid column. I need to show the number with two decimal points.

I have a silverlight DataGrid that I'm adding columns to dynamically.  I create the column and apply a dynamic binding (which I know works)

```
    public static DataGridTextColumn CreateFloatColumn(int index, string fieldName, string header, string description)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        column.Header = header;
        column.HeaderStyle = BuildColumnHeaderStyle(description);
        Binding newBinding = new Binding("floatValuesList[" + index + "]");
        column.Binding = newBinding;
        column.CellStyle = BuildCellStyle(fieldName, description);
        return column;
    }
```

Now I also need to format the value.  In this case it is a float value being shown.  How do I apply formatting to the binding?  At this point all I want is the number and two decimal points to show, but I'd like it to be a little flexible and let me show a variable number of decimal points.

(Edit: Removed string IValueConverter concept to keep the question cleaner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, and I think I was misleading in how I added a potential solution using a value converter to my original question - so sorry about that.  The solution turned out to be simple.  You pass the format string along with the binding.

```
        column.Binding.StringFormat = "0.00";
```

Here is the full solution

```
    public static DataGridTextColumn CreateFloatColumn(int index, string fieldName, string header, string description)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        column.Header = header;
        column.HeaderStyle = BuildColumnHeaderStyle(description);
        column.Binding = new Binding("floatValuesList[" + index + "]");
        column.Binding.StringFormat = "0.00";
        column.CellStyle = BuildFloatCellStyle(fieldName, description);
        return column;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do: `newBinding.ConverterParameter = "formatString";`

Comment: Wish I could delete comments.  Simple answer was use the binding stringFormat to specify decimal places to display.  Didn't need to use the valueConverter at all.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can delete comments, hover over it and you will see a x at the end of the comment :-) Cool, glad you came right, I suggest you look at value converters any case, they make life alot easier :-)